# The relation between sette and settimana: what is "mana"?

Tags: etymology

I am a beginner Italian learner.

I have learned "sette" (seven) and "settimana" (week) but the only word I have learned for day (so far) is "giorno". Does "mana" in "settimana" have something to do with a word for day in italian or does it mean something different or is it just a coincidence that there is a setti in settimana?

Comment: Just to clarify something already contained in the answers, *-mana* in itself doesn't actually “mean” something. It is just (the feminine form of) a suffix or, better, a kind of double suffix: *septem* (seven) > *septimus* (seventh) > *septimanus* (involving the seventh of something, especially days and legions).

Answer (score 10):

You are looking for the etymology of  ***[settimana](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/settimana)***, from Latin "septimus" used to indicate the space of seven days:

> - From Late Latin septimāna ‎(“week”), from the Latin septimānus ‎(“related to the seventh element of a series”, adjective), ***derived from septimus ‎(“seventh”).***

(Wiktionary)

So "mana" is the suffix coming from -mus - manus and later -māna

Comment: Actually if I understand correctly the suffix is *-anus* not *-manus* (like in *Octavianus* derived from *Octavius*)

Answer (score 7):

It's not a coincidence, but mana means nothing in Italian. It comes from the Latin word septimanus, that means sevenfold.